# How does the Rust compiler tokenize '>' vs '>>' in generics?

Tags: parsing, compilation, rust, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I've written many simple tokenizers and recursive-descent parsers, so I'm familiar with the basic concepts of how they work. But I was surprised when I stumbled upon the following Rust code:

```
Option<Option<i32>>
```

We know that Rust has a `>>` shift operator, so I think a naive tokenizer would output a `>>` token here, which the parser would see as an error (because it expects two `>` tokens instead).

But clearly the Rust compiler understands the situation and handles it correctly. What's going on here?

- Does the tokenizer keep some state, somehow knowing that it needs to close an angle bracket?
- Does the parser check for `>>` and break it into two tokens that are pushed back into the token stream?
- Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at Rust parsing libraries to see how they handle it.

## Library comparisons

### Fuzzy-Pickles

This is a parser that I've written, so I'm most familiar with the concepts.

The tokenizer is a simple byte-by-byte parser which greedily [consumes the characters `>>` to create a `DoubleRightAngle`](https://github.com/shepmaster/fuzzy-pickles/blob/4e50f699c57cb9c29ebb8335cd44ac84a5c2bc19/src/tokenizer.rs#L461) token.

Once tokenization is done, all of these tokens are collected into a vector and a second parsing pass takes place. During this pass, the parsing location is a complicated index that [allows being "split"](https://github.com/shepmaster/fuzzy-pickles/blob/4e50f699c57cb9c29ebb8335cd44ac84a5c2bc19/src/parser/mod.rs#L539-L544). This allows the parser to decompose a `>>` into two `>` if needed. The specific parsing functions look for a `>>` or two recursive `>` depending on what is being parsed.

Both the tokenization and parsing are implemented using the [peresil](https://github.com/shepmaster/peresil) crate.

### Syn

Syn is another parsing library. Here, they use a related idea: each token is [composed of multiple spans](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/6183fb539a1f55a153b01d23a23217188fc829d2/src/token.rs#L349-L351), one for each character. That is, the [`Shr`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.5/syn/token/struct.Shr.html) struct has a `spans: [Span; 2]` field.

### Rustc

It appears that the compiler allows ["gluing" multiple tokens into a bigger one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/66bf391c3aabfc77f5f7139fc9e6944f995d574e/src/libsyntax/parse/token.rs#L565-L570). During parsing, [`>>` can be "consumed" and replaced with a `>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/66bf391c3aabfc77f5f7139fc9e6944f995d574e/src/libsyntax/parse/parser.rs#L701-L737):

```
token::BinOp(token::Shr) => {
    let span = self.token.span.with_lo(self.token.span.lo() + BytePos(1));
    Some(self.bump_with(token::Gt, span))
}
token::BinOpEq(token::Shr) => {
    let span = self.token.span.with_lo(self.token.span.lo() + BytePos(1));
    Some(self.bump_with(token::Ge, span))
}
token::Ge => {
    let span = self.token.span.with_lo(self.token.span.lo() + BytePos(1));
    Some(self.bump_with(token::Eq, span))
}
```

## Additional points

There's an additional wrinkle around whitespace. A parser should parse both of both of these types equivalently:

```
Option<Option<i32>>
Option < Option < i32 > >
```

However, it should not parse these expressions equivalently:

```
a >>= 1
a >> = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's actually an issue describing some of this in quite a lot of detail: [#13: "The parser"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-guide/issues/13)

The reality is that the Rust token pipeline (tokenizer + lexer) is a relatively simple recursive descent parser with lookahead (which explains a ton of syntactic errors you get when you write incorrect code, by the way. For instance, forget to close a bracket and the parser will get stuck in that block, complaining about the limits of the block). Each token is ingested, state is kept between tokens, and an additional token is peeked at for lookahead purposes.

When Rust encounters something it should open a separate state for (such as your example), this is kept in the state to be able to deal with precisely this. As the language is pretty neatly conceived, there are no real ambiguities outside of references and reference calls (things like `*variable.call()` - do you mean `(*variable).call()` or `*(variable.call())`? Rust makes you specify this explicitly).

When it comes to type definitions like what you've described, there is no ambiguity as the shift operator cannot be in that space by definition. The same goes for the turbofish operator - the `::` precedent indicates that a type is going to be next.

So, the answer is "something else" - strict lexer rules and a stateful parser.

Answer (score 2):

The lexer is not independent from the parser, so it has a bit of context. Furthermore, about your precise question, the Rust types can only be found in precise places:

- In the function signatures: obviously, there cannot be any confusion with the operators.
- After the `:` sigil: there again cannot be any ambiguity since the colon indicates that a type will be written:

  ```rust
  let x: Vec<_> = some_iterator.collect();
  ```
- In the turbofish operator:

  ```rust
  let x = some_iterator.collect::<Vec<_>>();
  ```

  That notation exists for this only purpose to not create an ambiguity.
- In the trait dependent types:

  ```rust
  impl trait Foo for Bar {
      type Dependent = Vec<u8>;
  }
  ```

  The `type` keyword clearly indicate that there will be a type.

As you can see, the Rust team has carefully designed the syntax so that no ambiguity can exist in the grammar.

Comment: *That notation exists for this only purpose to not create an ambiguity* — there's talk of removing turbofish; how does that change your answer?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Many traditional parsers have a tokenization step that is completely independent from the semantic of the language and wouldn't know whether it's parsing a type or an expression to yield the right tokens. That seems to be the kind of tokenizer-parser pipeline that the OP is talking about.

Comment: @mcarton Is there really any programming language where the lexer is totally independent of the parser? A bit of context is often necessary.

Comment: @Shepmaster really? While I've certainly seen people complain about the syntax of the turbofish, I've never seen a serious proposal to remove it yet. I don't see how it could be done without causing many of the headaches that it prevents.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios probably not many modern languages are pure this any more no. But it's still a common approach in courses, and lexing and parsing isn't limited to programming languages.

Comment: @mcarton https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2527. I believe there was some work put into a crater run even, but I'm not finding that now.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I think that pull request ended with the now famous [Lament of the Turbofish](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/test/ui/bastion-of-the-turbofish.rs).